# Integrating OpenSceneGraph with Qt

Tags: qt, opengl, scenegraph, openscenegraph

I have fiddled around with OpenGL on Qt. But now I want to have complex scenes. (With multiple COLLADA/MD2 models loaded).

For this I'm thinking of using OpenSceneGraph (OSG). **Is it possible to integrate OSG with Qt**? If so how to?

Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

OpenSceneGraph has an osgQt library that makes it easy to integrate OpenSceneGraph within Qt. Head up to the the samples and specifically the [osgviewerQt](https://github.com/openscenegraph/osgQt/blob/master/examples/osgviewerQt/osgviewerQt.cpp) one!

Answer (score 1):

Yes - I haven't worked on OSG for a year but there was a very good Qt widget in OSG that worked well enough for a commercial product.

With the new improvements in openGL in 4.8 it should be even better

You should probably search the [osg forum](http://forum.openscenegraph.org/)

Comment: osgQt Widgets for OSG currently don't work when using Qt 5.x and multithreaded rendering

Answer (score 1):

Just to point out at another resource (which works with QOpenGLWidget): an article [Making Qt and OpenSceneGraph play nice](http://bastian.rieck.ru/blog/posts/2014/qt_and_openscenegraph/) by Bastian Rieck. It will be useful for those who are interested in doing **render of different scenes on different widgets** while performing **updates on demand** only (without timer). The article has a link to a source code.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple class that derives from QOpenGLWidget, and can be used as a normal widget, that encapsulates osgViewer::GraphicsWindowEmbedded, and also (optionally) allows to use the mouse inside the widget to control the camera.

Its usage is as simple as:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>

#include "QtOSGWidget.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QApplication qapp(argc, argv);
    QMainWindow window;

    QtOSGWidget widget(&window);

    window.setCentralWidget(&widget);
    window.show();
    return qapp.exec();
}
```

It can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/equilibr/osgQt).